# Sending parameter request with RestSharp in C#. Getting Error: Required field \"expr\" missing in JSON body

Tags: c#, restsharp, webapi

I am writing a simple calculation machine application in Windows `Form` application. I want to perform operations using math `js web api` (post), but where I call api I get this error:

> Error: Required field \"expr\" missing in JSON body" // in Response

My code is here  :

```
   private void Equals_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        var client = new RestClient("http://api.mathjs.org/v4/");
        var request = new RestRequest("/expr", Method.POST);
        var deger = txtCevap.Text; // txtCevap.Text is my calculator parameter
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(deger);
        request.AddParameter("application/json; charset=utf-8", json, ParameterType.RequestBody);
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

    }
```

Can you help me in this topic? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

for api.mathjs.org, you are required to pass string or string[] with expr element. Please review their [requirements here.](https://api.mathjs.org/)

```
    var client = new RestClient("http://api.mathjs.org/v4/");
    var request = new RestRequest("", Method.POST);
    var deger = @"{""expr"": ""2+1""}"; // txtCevap.Text is my calculator parameter

    request.AddJsonBody(deger);

    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

response object's content looks like below that you can easily deserialize. they always have Result and Error.

```
"{\"result\":\"3\",\"error\":null}"

dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content);
string answer = result["result"].ToString()
```

Comment: deger is a strring value, haw can I add request?

Comment: For simple text, request.AddParameter("application/json", deger, ParameterType.RequestBody);

Comment: Also, remove the slash from restrequest that appears before the word expr

Comment: When I applied, I got this error : "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n<head>\n<meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n<title>Error</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<pre>Internal Server Error</pre>\n</body>\n</html>\n"

Comment: @gözdeyıldız Updated my answer to do what you are looking for.

Comment: thank you for help, I tried other a method as WebClient. It is working now :)

Comment: @gözdeyıldız please mark the post as answered if it help resolve your matter.